# this code class but give message "not all paths return a value'

Tags: c#

```
 public Boolean login(string n1, string n2)
    {
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from userdata where username='" + n1 + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, con);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        con.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            con.Open();
            string checkpassword = "select password from userdata where username='" + n1 + "'";
            SqlCommand passcomm = new SqlCommand(checkpassword, con);
            string password = passcomm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");
            if (password == n2) return false;
            else return true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: If `temp !=1 ` then you're not returning a value...

Comment: What do you want to return if `temp != 1`?

Comment: A method in C# which has a non-void return type *must* return a value. Also, your database calls are prone to SQL injection.

Comment: return false or true

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error message seems clear enough to me: not all possible code execution paths in the method eventually reach a statement that returns a value.

This is not allowed. You have declared your method as returning a value of type `Boolean`. If the flow of execution through the method reaches the end of the method without executing a `return` statement, how is the compiler supposed to know what value the method should return?

You can fix the compiler error by adding a `return` statement to the end of the method (after the closing brace of the `if` statement, but before the closing brace of the method declaration itself). I.e. either `return true;` or `return false;`.

You don't provide enough information here for anyone to know which is correct, though given the "password" nature of the code, it seems like returning `false` is safest.

Alternatively, you might want to throw an exception instead of returning a value, since if `temp` is not equal to `1` after executing your query, presumably that means something went wrong with your database.